# How to enable Mathjax for chat on the Android mobile browser?

Tags: support, mathjax, chat

Suppose I am a user of stack exchange chat. And I am on Android mobile. My questions are **1**) How do I enable Mathjax In chat. Can I? I am asking as the question asked was answered for computer not for mobile.

Comment: To my knowledge, mathjax on chat over mobile is not doable. The second question should be asked separately, to keep things organized.

Comment: You should delete the second question from this post and then ask a separate thread with it.#

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  you mean I should ask the second question as a different question or should I change the Para? Please clear

Comment: As for mobile chatjax - maybe it *is* possible via the same, or a similar bookmarklet? You'll need to be able to use bookmarklets, and there do seem to be solutions available, but they'll change from browser to browser.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thanks for helping.

Comment: If you *do* ask your second question separately, you should flesh it out some more. In principle, the procedure is the same - you drag the ChatJax bookmarklet to your bookmarks bar and then you activate it. If that doesn't work for some reason, you should explain in detail what you did and in which way it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ChatJax bookmarklet](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) appears to be designed for both desktop and mobile browsers, and indeed there's a specific version for "troublesome mobile browsers" to try out if you find it's not working.

As to how you can install a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) on a mobile browser - that will vary depending on the browser, and it may not be possible on some browsers. Your mileage may vary here, and I'm reluctant to recommend solutions as the different routes may or may not apply depending on individual situations (such as e.g. willingness to sync mobile and desktop bookmarks).

Alternatively, you could install Tampermonkey as an app and then run the [ChatJax++ userscript over it](https://github.com/vyznev/chatjax), though again that has some significant overheads.

Generally, to the best of my understanding, rather few people in this site's community use MathJax for chat over mobile, given how hard it is to write LaTeX on mobile keyboards so you're mostly doomed to one-sided conversations even if you can see other people's MathJax rendered correctly.

Comment: you can't even see correctly rendered MathJax in chats on Android, as far as I can see. (I do type LaTeX on a mobile kbd sometimes, it's not really too hard, just slow :-))